# Hadoop plugin (1.0.3) for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to Hadoop. Can anyone tell me how to create Hadoop Plugin (version 1.0.3) for eclipse? In fact, they removed the plugin from /hadoop-x.x.x/contrib/ (in my case, x.x.x = 1.0.3)
There's a eclipse-plugin in /hadoop-x.x.x/src/contrib/.

By the way, What's the "typical way" to develop a MapReduce app using eclipse (words count for example) in term of:

- Configuration (Standalone or Pseudodistributed...)
- Coding convention (Folder structure, code, debug...)

Comment: i don't know about 1.0.3 but 0.20.203 comes with eclipse plugin at path /contrib/eclipse-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you have Hadoop Eclipse plugin installed and configured

in eclipse create a mapreduce project, it provides required dependencies of hadoop and other jars.

then you need to create Main class, Mapper class and Reducer class, In Main class you need to configure Job. [wordcount example](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount)

once done you can run main program as run on hadoop, no need to start hadoop before running the program

for 1.0.3 plugin:
Apache has remove the plugin from Hadoop installation folder. Instead you can find Eclipse Plugin source code with build.xml file at "${HADOOP_HOME}\hadoop-1.0.3\src\contrib\eclipse-plugin".  or you can simply download it from [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8n7aI4e8I_rWnZ5ZTFrTWNRSkE)

Comment: For the wordcount example, it's ok. And for the plugin, can you figure out how must I do to create a .jar file from that bunch of code ? Thanks.

Comment: plugin code is with build.xml, so you can build it using ant(http://ant.apache.org/). anyway you can also download it from http://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8n7aI4e8I_rWnZ5ZTFrTWNRSkE